# PHP plugin to create barcode image

Tags: php, barcode

I want to know if there is any free PHP Bar code generator tool available which can generate PDF417, QR, AZTEC type bar code as as image file. I searched on internet but didnot get any free PHP tool that can generate these 3 types of bar code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't find a single library that will do all the formats but you will find different libraries that can do each part for you, most of them are available through composer.

Here's a short list of some i would recommand

- [pdf417](https://github.com/ihabunek/pdf417-php)
- [qrcode](https://github.com/endroid/QrCode)
- [metzli (for aztec)](https://github.com/z38/metzli)